# android ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class---from developing android apps

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-emulator

i got an error like this

```
03-15 08:33:51.474: D/AndroidRuntime(1468): Shutting down VM
03-15 08:33:51.474: W/dalvikvm(1468): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a80ba8)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): Process: com.pongodev.restaurant, PID: 1468
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.pongodev.restaurant/com.pongodev.restaurant.Home}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.pongodev.restaurant.Home" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pongodev.restaurant-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.pongodev.restaurant-1, /system/lib]]
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.pongodev.restaurant.Home" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pongodev.restaurant-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.pongodev.restaurant-1, /system/lib]]
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
03-15 08:33:51.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     ... 11 more
```

and here is my AndroidMainifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.8" package="com.pongodev.restaurant"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <permission android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x20000" android:required="true" />
    <application android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCi43x8rh1xwonf15SQ2faHLPKCJUkzAn8" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.SettingPreferences" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.CategoryList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.MenuList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.MenuDetail" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.ShareMenu" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.Contact" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.News" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.NewsDetail" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.YourOrder" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.pongodev.restaurant.Reservation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please teach me how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: is com.pongodev.restaurant.Home from a different project?

Comment: `com.pongodev.restaurant.Home` is not in your manifest.

Comment: How can i fix it? Bro